# How to verify if the MacBook Pro HDD cable is faulty?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hdd

Is it possible that I take out the HDD cable and test it with multimeter to see if all wires are connected, etc? Is there a pin diagram for it?

The problem: 
I have this MacBook Pro mid 2009, lat year the hard disk was behaving fishy, so I bought a new HDD and installed it. Problem solved, till now. The same problem is back.
Mac does not boot. Sometimes I can boot in the Bootcamp windows though. And when I put the  HDD in enclousure and connect to a PC with USB, it is just fine. Even it passed the SeaTools test. When I connect this HDD via USB to my mac, it can boot mac normally, but after some time it crashes.

Another test I made: I put the old HDD in the Mac, it booted fine, but after some time it crashed.

Now I am not sure if it is the HDD cable which is faulty or the HDD or something else.

Is there a way I can test HDD cable seperately and be sure it is faulty before spending 50 quids on a new one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would use a OHM meter, to test the wires.

The cable and the plugs are 1:1 thus same pin on both sides.

The meter should show full connection, thus no resistance at all.

Some meters have the Audible signal for testing the connection.

I know you know this but [here it is anyway](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1534/en_US/MacBook_13inch_Hard_Drive_DIY.pdf).